# Grails - Dependencies problems

Tags: grails

I'm new to Grails and I'm starting a new Project (a plugin)

Now, when I'm trying to execute some commands from ggts, like generate-controller, run-app I get the following

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [hibernate, codecs, controllers, dataSource, scaffolding, urlMappings, converters, mimeTypes, filters, groovyPages]
- Plugin: hibernate
   - Dependencies:
       ! dataSource (Required: 2.2 > *, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
       - i18n (Required: 2.2 > *, Found: 2.2.4) 
       ! core (Required: 2.2 > *, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
       - domainClass (Required: 2.2 > *, Found: 2.2.4) 
- Plugin: codecs
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
- Plugin: controllers
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
       - i18n (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 2.2.4) 
       ! urlMappings (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
- Plugin: dataSource
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
- Plugin: scaffolding
   - Dependencies:
       ! controllers (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
       ! groovyPages (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
- Plugin: urlMappings
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
- Plugin: converters
   - Dependencies:
       ! controllers (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
       - domainClass (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 2.2.4) 
- Plugin: mimeTypes
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
       - servlets (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 2.2.4) 
       ! controllers (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
- Plugin: filters
   - Dependencies:
       ! controllers (Required: 2.2.4, Found: Not Installed) [INVALID]
- Plugin: groovyPages
   - Dependencies:
       ! core (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 0.1) [INVALID]
       - i18n (Required: 2.2.4, Found: 2.2.4)
```

I also have similar problems when I try to install a plugin.

This is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.21'
    }

    plugins {
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
              ":release:2.2.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: Also, reduce the number of variables - does it work from the commandline? It might be a real problem, or might just be GGTS misconfiguration

Comment: Weird. I created a simple plugin from command line. Added some domain-classes and some services. Runs beautifully. I imported the project in ggts, it starts throwing this problem (when trying to run from terminal or ggts).

Comment: Witch version of GGTS are you using?

Comment: add more repositories in BuildConfig.groovy: grailsPlugins(),        grailsHome(), grailsCentral(), mavenLocal() and mavenCentral(). I suppose you missed grailsPlugins() repo